# How to get routevalues from URL with htmlhelpers or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-routing

I have this MVC MapRoute

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Authenticated",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{foo}/{bar}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "WelcomePage", Foo = "0", Bar = "0" }
);
```

And URL

```
http://localhost/mysite/controller/action/2/1
```

How can I with JavaScript recieve the `2` and `1`? I would prefer a solution with as little substring work as possible, because that would easially lead to alot of errors I think.

Note the URL might end with ?filter=xx sometimes, if it matters.

I have tryed

```
var foo= ViewContext.RouteData.Values["foo"];
var bar= ViewContext.RouteData.Values["bar"];

alert('foo: ' + foo);
alert('bar: ' + bar);
```

Result:
`e: ReferenceError: ViewContext is not defined`

Comment: Oh it's razor i forgot the @{ }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To write server side code to be processed by razor engine, you have to prepend your statement with `@`. That will only work if that Javascript is embedded on the view.

You can also do it with Javascript. Something like this should do the trick

```
var urlParts = location.href.split('/');
var foo = urlParts[6];
var bar = urlParts[7];
```

Comment: splitting the string is going to by far be the fastest , I don't see a problem with readability there at all

Comment: I will try, looks fine at first glanse. Only worry would be if 6 and 7 would change

Comment: Do you know how I can fix this? e: TypeError: location.split is not a function

Comment: Use "window.location.href" instead of "location"?

Comment: Fixed the mistake, please use location.href

Comment: I worked well. I am not thrilled about the hardcode indexies at all though. You don't have another solution without any hardcode values mate? :)

Comment: @not of the top of my head. I'll update I come up with something. If the script is embedded on your view, you can check your initial solution fixing the syntax. It would fail the same if the rounte change though.

Comment: This only occur when I'm logged in. And for that I only have one route. It would have been nice if there was some helper where I only had to tell it my routename ("Authenticated"), and the (foo) and (bar), and then it somehow ceverly find and give me those values. You know what I mean? :) But thanks anyways, I'm implementing you're solution now.